# How to get list of all items that have a particular property, in Wikidata?

Tags: wikidata

How collect Wikidata's entities by a certain property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are familiar with [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL), Wikidata (not to be confused with DBpedia) has an [official endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/) and a page with [example queries](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples). The following example lists all countries with the property [sovereign state](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3624078):

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?cid ?country WHERE {
    ?cid wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078 .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?cid rdfs:label ?country filter (lang(?country) = "en") .
    }
}
```

For more information, please visit [official reference for data access](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access).

Answer (score 9):

While not the most script-friendly, here is the easiest/fastest way to get what you want without any third-party:

1) Go to the [Wikidata page of the property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1174)

2) Click [What links here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Property:P1174) in the left panel's Tools section:

[image: Wikidata property: What links here]

3) Enjoy the paged list:

[image: Wikidata list]

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by using [MediaWiki API for Wikidata with backlinks query](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bbacklinks)

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=backlinks&blnamespace=0&bllimit=500&&bltitle=Property:P1086
```

In above example **blnamespace=0** means the result list to include only **items** (without user pages, talk pages, templates, etc.). The example is for [atomic number](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1086) (P1086) property.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what property you are looking for (the question isn't that clear) you could use [DBpedia](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) and SPARQL any entities that have a connection with a certain link/property.