# Get list of all wikidata properties used to link to an item

Tags: wikidata, sparql

The first part of my question is, is there a SPARQL equivalent of the "What links here" link? E.g. as described at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5271/20321

I tried:

```
WHERE {  ?item wdt:?property wd:Q1174 . }
```

which gave a syntax error, and:

```
WHERE {  ?item wdt:* wd:Q1174 . }
```

which doesn't give an error, but only returns one row: the item in the query!

The second part of my question is how can I get a list of all unique properties that are used to link to the item of interest? This is the bit I'm interested in, as I suspect there will typically just be 1 or 2 properties used for 99% of the links, and that any others are probably mistakes, that are good candidates for fixing to improve data quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first part of my question is, is there a SPARQL equivalent of the "What links here" link?
>
> The second part of my question is how can I get a list of all unique properties that are used to link?

Assuming you are interested in [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements) statements only:

```
select distinct ?subject ?subjectLabel {
  values (?item) {(wd:Q42)}
  ?subject ?predicate ?item .
  ?property wikibase:directClaim ?predicate
  service wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20distinct%20%3Fsubject%20%3FsubjectLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20values%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ42%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fpredicate%0A%20%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D))

and

```
select distinct ?property ?propertyLabel {
  values (?item) {(wd:Q42)}
  ?subject ?predicate ?item .
  ?property wikibase:directClaim ?predicate
  service wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20values%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ42%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fpredicate%0A%20%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D))

respectively.

**Update**

If you want to use the label service with items that have large number of incoming links, you should place it outside of the inner query.

```
select ?property ?propertyLabel ?count {
  {
  select ?property (count(*) as ?count) {
    values (?item) {(wd:Q30)}
    ?subject ?predicate ?item .
    ?property wikibase:directClaim ?predicate
  } group by ?property  having (?count > 0) 
  }
  service  wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} order by desc(?count)
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fcount%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20select%20%3Fproperty%20%28count%28%2a%29%20as%20%3Fcount%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20values%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ30%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fpredicate%0A%20%20%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fproperty%20%20having%20%28%3Fcount%20%3E%200%29%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20service%20%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%20order%20by%20desc%28%3Fcount%29%20)

Comment: Thanks! A variation on your 2nd query, I changed first line to `select ?property ?propertyLabel (COUNT(?propertyLabel) as ?cnt)` then added `GROUP BY ?property ?propertyLabel`, and optionally `ORDER BY DESC(?cnt)`, to the end.

Comment: If I drop the `wikibase:directClaim` I get over double the entries: 20 --> 43. Every wdt:NN has a ps:NN equivalent, each with identical count. But also "schema:about" (110), and then pq:P50 and pq:P5869 (1 each). I can't work out if the "pq" are typos for "ps" (and if fixed, then another "wdt" would magically appear?)

Comment: @DarrenCook, about `ps:` and `pq:`, see [Data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Data_model). My query lists only `wdt:` properties and subjects connected via them.

Comment: pinging you again for this meta thread https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/413/1511